# How to replace parts of a string with React Link component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a text (random text) like this one:

```
bla bla bla (name of link)[link] bla bla bla (name of link)[link]
```

I need to replace all of `(name of link)[link]` with `Link` React component:

```
<Link to={link}>name of link</Link>
```

What I want to see:

```
bla bla bla <Link to='/testRoute'>Test name</Link> bla bla bla <Link to='/testRoute'>Test name</Link>
```

`(name of link)[link]` in the text can be absent, and can meet many times.

How can I replace all matches by  in the text?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: I tried, but probably not absolutely true I used. It is possible to set an example on my text how to make it?

Comment: Show us what you tried before asking us to do it for you.

Comment: I found [name of link] by text.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, ''), but I don't know what need to do for replace for completely <Link to={link}>name of link</Link> immediately

Comment: `<Link to={link}>name of link</Link>`is JSX version of React component, you can't just replace `(name of link)[link]` with `<Link to={link}>name of link</Link>` string

Comment: Sooo... What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 3):

Try to split `bla bla bla (name of link)[link] bla bla bla (name of link)[link]` string into an array of substrings, so you will have the following array:

```
const arrayOfStrings = [
    'bla bla bla',
    '(name of link)[link]',
    'bla bla bla',
    '(name of link)[link]',
];
```

And then you can use `.map()` to create new array with valid React elements:

```
    arrayOfStrings.map((str, i) => {
        const isLink = str === '(name of link)[link]';//of course you need to replace it with regex

        if (isLink) {
            const linkName = 'name of link';//replace it with regex, so you can get dynamic link name from str
            const link = 'link';//replace it with regex, so you can get dynamic link from str 

            return <Link key={i} to={link}>{linkName}</Link>;
        }
        else {
            return <span key={i}>{str}</span>;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `regexify-string` ([npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regexify-string))

> npm install --save regexify-string

```
regexifyString({
        pattern: /\[.*?\]/gim,
        decorator: (match, index) => {
            return (
                <Link
                    to={SOME_ROUTE}
                    onClick={onClick}
                >
                    {match}
                </Link>
            );
        },
        input: 'Some initial string with [link]',
    });
```